# Entity Framework 5 always try to connect to sqlexpress instead of local db

Tags: entity-framework, localdb

I'm using Visual Studio Express for web to follow this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj193542.
The tutorial tells that

> By convention DbContext has created a database for you.
>
> If a local SQL Express instance is available (installed by default
>   with Visual Studio 2010) then Code First has created the database on
>   that instance If SQL Express isn’t available then Code First will try
>   and use LocalDb (installed by default with Visual Studio 2012) The
>   database is named after the fully qualified name of the derived
>   context, in our case that is
>   CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample.BloggingContext

So, it should use localdb. But when I try to access my model, I can see in debug that the connection string points to .\SQLEXPRESS, althought I don't have sqlexpress. So, I got a timeout exception ...

Why localdb isn't used ?

Note that if I set explicitly the connectionstring to localdb, it's working ... 
Note too, that if I use Vs Express for Desktop, it's working too...

What's wrong with the Vs Express for web ?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/17137504/62072

Answer (score 5):

[EF Connections explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606)
Tell EF the factory to use by default, eg

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```